# \bigints package is not working fine together with \lmodern

Tags: amsmath, integral, lmodern

I'm trying to get big integral symbol, so I tried with '\bigints' but I've found that

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{bigints}    

\newcommand*\norm[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}

\begin{document}
    
    $$ \bigints \dfrac{\dfrac{1}{2}}{\norm{s}+1} ds =  \int \dfrac{\dfrac{1}{2}}{\norm{s}+1} ds$$
    
\end{document}
```

produces [image]

while

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{bigints}    

\newcommand*\norm[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}

\begin{document}
    
    $$ \bigints \dfrac{\dfrac{1}{2}}{\norm{s}+1} ds =  \int \dfrac{\dfrac{1}{2}}{\norm{s}+1} ds$$
    
\end{document}
```

produces [image]

I don't know the internal code of '\lmodern' so, what's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fd file for lmodern gives a fixed size for the extension font, you could allow it to be scaled to the current font size.

[image]

Although I'd never use the display fraction in the numerator.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\DeclareFontFamily{OMX}{lmex}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{lmex}{m}{n}{%
   <->lmex10%  was  <->sfixed*lmex10%
   }{}
\usepackage{bigints}    

\newcommand*\norm[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}

\begin{document}
    
    \[ \bigints \dfrac{\dfrac{1}{2}}{\norm{s}+1} ds =  \int \dfrac{\dfrac{1}{2}}{\norm{s}+1} ds\]
    
\end{document}
```

The default for cmex is also fixed but amsmath extends that to a larger range (but just for computer modern)